# Decryption with the public key in iphone

Tags: iphone, rsa

I have a public key and an encrypted string. I could encrypt with the publickey successfully.But when i try to decrypt using the publickey it fails. I mean when i pass the publickey to***seckeyDecrypt*** it fails.

I have Googled and found out that, by default ***kSecAttrCanDecrypt*** is false for public keys.So When i import the public key, i have added this particular line ,

   **[publicKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kSecAttrCanDecrypt];**

But there is no improvement it still fails. Please somebody help.

EDIT: 
Apple's Certificate,Key and Trust Services Says,

kSecAttrCanEncrypt Default false for private keys, true for public keys.
kSecAttrCanDecrypt Default true for private keys, false for public keys.
Which means, the values can be changed right?. My server does not sign(Convert as a digest) the content. They just encrypt using the private key which is to be decrypted at my(in iphone) end. Is that possible?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of [asymmetric cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) is that you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key.

EDIT: If you're signing and verifying, you should use the associated APIs.  For example, you can check this capability with `kSecAttrCanSign` and `kSecAttrCanVerify`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I mean  i need the reverse part. # A signing algorithm that, given a message and a private key, produces a signature.
# A signature verifying algorithm that, given a message, public key and a signature, either accepts or rejects the message's claim to authenticity.

Comment: Vignesh, use the corresponding _private_ key to decrypt the ciphertext. Or, don't. Public Key Cryptography is not safe to use directly on data -- please use Public Key Crypto ONLY to encrypt random session keys (keys used for symmetric ciphers) or sign message digest hashes.

Comment: @sarnoid, if all you need is confidentiality, you can encrypt the data directly.  This isn't done only because it's inefficient.

Comment: thanks for the reply.But What is the use of kSecAttrCanDecrypt ?. just to know. Thank you again.

Comment: @vignesh, I think it's a check for when you're doing encryption/decryption (rather than signing/verifying).